# Play Framework Template compiling is slow and crashes

Tags: playframework, template-engine, playframework-2.2

I am using Play Framework with sbt and have big troubles compiling templates. Each time I change a template the compiling takes a very long time, runs out of memory sometimes, simply crashes for different reasons, or gets stuck.

I edited the build.sbt to enable a bigger perm size:

```
javaOptions ++= Seq("-XX:PermSize=512M", "-XX:MaxPermSize=4096M",
                    "-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC", "-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled")
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This issue still the major problem in Play Development :(. If you are using Play 2.2.2, you can try the new version of sbt. Take a look in this link(https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/S_-wYW5Tcvw). They implemented a new algorithm to detect modifications in scala classes...